# how do I quit a command in the terminal

Tags: terminal

How do I quit a command in the terminal? I wrote cat only and it's "doing nothing" so how do I terminate the command and come back to the directory path in the terminal were I was?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? And what do you mean by "doing nothing"?

Comment: I believe you should ask these types of questions on superuser, not stackoverflow. That's maybe why you couldn't find an answer to your question by searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it sounds like you're on Linux or other POSIX system---

You're cat command is waiting patiently for input from its standard input, which in this case is the terminal.

If you type Cntrl-D, an End-Of-File condition will be sent to the cat command, and it will finish.